# Match observations in two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I want to use elements from one dataframe to search through a column from the other dataframe. And I need to narrow down this dataframe by the matches. And then continue narrowing down element by element. Look to the sample code, which can explain better.

```
df1    col1   

1      apples      
2      oranges     
3      apples    
4      banana  
5      grapes
6      mangoes
7      oranges
8      banana
```

df1 has only one column in it. Meanwhile df2 has 2 columns in it. setID & col1

```
df2 setID   col1

1   1   apples      
2   1   oranges     
3   1   oranges
4   1   mangoes
5   1   grapes
6   1   banana  
7   1   banana
8   1   apples    
10  2   apples      
11  2   oranges     
12  2   apples    
13  2   banana  
14  2   grapes
15  2   mangoes
16  2   banana
17  2   oranges
18  3   apples      
19  3   banana  
20  3   oranges     
21  3   apples    
22  3   grapes
23  3   mangoes
24  3   oranges
25  3   banana
26  4   apples      
27  4   oranges     
28  4   apples    
29  4   grapes
30  4   grapes
31  4   oranges     
32  4   banana  
33  4   banana
```

As you can see there are some repeating setIDs. They mark one set. The order of the set is important. Please note that the df1$col1 does not have to be the same length as a set from df2. Nor do they have to be an exact match. They just have to be a close enough match. In this case df1$col1 is closest a match to df2$setID = 2 with only the last two elements out of order. The reason why they dont have to be an exact match is because I want to use a "search as you type" approach. I do not want to match df1$col1 as it is to a setID on df2. I want to narrow down the possible set by going through element by element. Assume that you get the elements of df1 one by one and not as a complete dataframe. For example:

Find a match for df1$col1[1] from df2 and save any sets that contains the match to a tempdf. It doesnt matter if a match for df1$col1[1] is found more than once in the same set. If it is found at least once then that set will be added to tempdf.

What needs to be retrieved at the end is a setID that corresponds to the set that matches as close to df1. In this case the tempdf will be the same as df2 as all the sets include "apples". Next will be what matches df1$col1[2] against the tempdf given that the first element is a match. I guess df1$col1[1:2] from tempdf. This results in:

```
tempdf  setID   col1

1   1   apples      
2   1   oranges     
3   1   oranges
4   1   mangoes
5   1   grapes
6   1   banana  
7   1   banana
8   1   apples    
10  2   apples      
11  2   oranges     
12  2   apples    
13  2   banana  
14  2   grapes
15  2   mangoes
16  2   banana
17  2   oranges
26  4   apples      
27  4   oranges     
28  4   apples    
29  4   grapes
30  4   grapes
31  4   oranges     
32  4   banana  
33  4   banana
```

Basically setID = 3 is omitted. As this continues with the 3rd element from df1 the new tempdf will contain only setID 2 & 4. The loop (my thinking to solve this) would end once only one setID remains, in this case setID = 2. Therefore setID = 2 would be considered as a close match for df1.

Of course feel free to advice on a better approach than this one.

Comment: `lapply(split(df2[, "col1", drop = FALSE], df2$setID), function(x) identical(df1, x))`?

Comment: What is your expected answer if `df1` has less rows than a group in `df2`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the "compare" package, which would allow you to compare allowing for different transformations.

Here are a couple of examples to consider....

Starting sample data. Note `setID == 4`, which has all the values, but in the wrong order.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("apples", "oranges", "apples", "banana"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1
##      col1
## 1  apples
## 2 oranges
## 3  apples
## 4  banana

df2 <- structure(list(setID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4), col1 = c("apples", "oranges", "apples", "banana", 
    "apples", "grapes", "oranges", "apples", "oranges", "grapes", 
    "banana", "banana", "apples", "apples", "banana", "oranges")), 
    .Names = c("setID", "col1"), 
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "21", "31", "41"), class = "data.frame")
df2
##    setID    col1
## 1      1  apples
## 2      1 oranges
## 3      1  apples
## 4      1  banana
## 5      2  apples
## 6      2  grapes
## 7      2 oranges
## 8      2  apples
## 9      3 oranges
## 10     3  grapes
## 11     3  banana
## 12     3  banana
## 13     4  apples
## 21     4  apples
## 31     4  banana
## 41     4 oranges
```

Load "compare" and do some comparisons:

```
library(compare)
lapply(split(df2[, "col1", drop = FALSE], df2$setID), 
       function(x) compare(df1, x))
## $`1`
## TRUE
## 
## $`2`
## FALSE [FALSE]
## 
## $`3`
## FALSE [FALSE]
## 
## $`4`
## FALSE [FALSE]
##
```

Allow all transformations before comparison (see `?compare` for details if you want to allow only for certain transformations).

```
lapply(split(df2[, "col1", drop = FALSE], df2$setID), 
       function(x) compare(df1, x, allowAll = TRUE))
## $`1`
## TRUE
## 
## $`2`
## FALSE [FALSE]
##   sorted
##   [col1] ignored case
##   renamed rows
##   [col1] ignored case
##   dropped row names
##   [col1] ignored case
## 
## $`3`
## FALSE [FALSE]
##   sorted
##   [col1] ignored case
##   renamed rows
##   [col1] ignored case
##   dropped row names
##   [col1] ignored case
## 
## $`4`
## TRUE
##   sorted
##   renamed rows
##   dropped row names
##
```

Comment: This is a cool answer. But can I ask if this is comparing row by row from df1? Because it looks a lot like comparing the whole column. In my case it needs to be row by row or a certain number of row by row. It cannot be a comparison of the whole column from df1 at once. I put it into a dataframe for easy comparison. But in reality the values will be compared as they are coming in. The goal for me to is find a match without comparing the whole df1 column.

Comment: @Nix, Sorry, but your comment's not really clear. Are you going to be using a `data.frame` or not?

Comment: Going to be using a data.frame. But its only to prove the theory. In the end product the set from df1(test set) will not be available in full for comparison. The test set will be populated one element at a time. So i want to start the search to narrow down the matching set as soon as "apples" is populated. With "oranges" appearing it will be further narrowed down. The easiest way i can explain is an autocorrect feature. The more letters you type the easier to predict the word.

Answer (score 0):

using base R:

```
split(df2,df2[,1])[by(df2[2],df2[1],function(x)all(x==df1))]
 $`1`
   setID    col1
 1     1  apples
 2     1 oranges
 3     1  apples
 4     1  banana
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to find `setID` groups in `df2` where the values in `col1` are *exactly* the same as in `df2`.

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(df2)[, all(col1 == df1$col1), by = setID][(V1)]
tmp
```

> ```
>    setID   V1
> 1:     1 TRUE
> ```

Now, the OP has requested to return the matching rows. This can be accomplished by either looking for matching values of `setID`

```
df2[setID %in% tmp$setID]
```

> ```
>    setID    col1
> 1:     1  apples
> 2:     1 oranges
> 3:     1  apples
> 4:     1  banana
> ```

or by joining (which presumably might be faster on large tables)

```
df2[tmp, on = "setID", .SD]
```

returning the same result.

#### Caveat

The sample datasets provided by the OP suggests that the number of rows in `df1` is the same as in each `setID` group in `df2`. The OP has not specified the expected result in case the number of rows differ.

Comment: My bad. I should have mentioned if the number of rows match. Assume that it doesnt. And that is why your method of matching exactly all the values will not work. I have updated my data sets better explain.